# woocommerce 2.6.4 eliminar barra lateral en productos individuales

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo en una web un blog con barra lateral a la derecha y en el resto de la web, la barra lateral no debe de aparecer. En la web tengo también el woocommerce para compras. Lo extraño es que en las páginas individuales de cada producto, aparece la barra lateral justo debajo de las imágenes de los productos PERO a la izquierda.

Esta barra no debiera de aparecer en ningún otro sitio que no sea el blog. He mirado mil veces los ajustes y no hay nada que indique una barra lateral a la izquierda (solo a la derecha y en el blog).

Así que tras todo esto, decidí meterme en los archivos .php del woocommerce con la esperanza de eliminarla desde ahí... y debería de haberla eliminado, pero la barra sigue.

Fui a single-product.php y eliminé este código

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
?>
```

Después de eliminarlo, fui a archive-product.php y eliminé lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
?>
```

Finalmente, fui al css habitual de mi wordpress y añadí la siguiente regla:

```
#content-woocomerece{
   width:100% !important;
    }
```

El !important lo añadí después al ver que no hacía efecto, pero ni con esas la barrita desaparece. Probé también lo siguiente (sustituyendo la regla css anterior por esta) pero tampoco funcionó:

```
.woocommerce #sidebar{display:none;}
```

También probé a poner en el functions.php lo siguiente sin éxito:

```
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
```

Con el CSS hice invisible la barra lateral con visibility:hidden solo en la barra de la tienda (en el blog continuaba la barra lateral correspondiente) pero el problema es que ocupa muchísimo esa barra lateral y deja un espacio en blanco enorme (motivo por el que quiero quitarla, ya que afea la tienda y encima de no tener nada útil para la tienda, ocupa muchísimo espacio y el resto lo deja en blanco).

```
aside.sidebar.sidebar_sidebar_right.alpha.units{
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

No se ya que mas intentar (la única línea que vi en sidebar.php relacionada con woocommerce no sirvió de nada eliminarla, así que la volví a poner).

Lo agradeceré muchísimo si alguien puede ayudarme. Dejo una imagen de como se ve y la barra que hay que eliminar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale, ya encontré como hacerlo... al final no era nada de código, si no una opción que estaba en la zona de widgets y que ayer tras buscar y buscar, no debí de ver.

En Widgets, en display everywhere, hay que eliminar todo lo que salga ahí si no quieres que se vea en todos los sitios (incluyendo aquellos en los que las opciones del tema no incluya) y poner los widgets del lado izquierdo seleccionando donde quieres que se vean y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]